# Corona SDK layering content over widget

Tags: widget, scrollview, layer, coronasdk

I am using Corona to build an interactive ebook with game elements. The problem I am having is that the text for the book is placed is a scrolling widget which is then masked. The menu buttons are currently unable to be pressed as the widget text is covering the buttons. I need to be able to layer the buttons so that they are "on top" of the widget. Please Help.

Many Thanks,

User

Answer (score 1):

After you show the text, do this:

button:toFront();

or better, put the buttons in a group, and keep that group (suing toFront() as needed) in front of the other things.

toFront() brings a object to front of its own group, so if the buttons are in the same group as the text, they will jump to front.

If you put several buttons in a single group, toFront() will only order the buttons between themselves, then you need to do toFront() in the group itself instead.

Everything has a "default" group (that is found by using display.getCurrentStage() )